# Deploy a web app using NPM but no bundler

Tags: javascript, npm, package, bundler

I'm in the process of migrating an existing ASP.NET 4 MVC app that has had years of work on scripts manually copy-pasted into the /Scripts/ folder or managed by NuGet. We want to use NPM going forward for all front-end packages, and use modules (instead of the current way we import scripts - script tags in HTML). However, since we have a few third-party components that cannot be converted to modules, we need to retain the ability to have inline JavaScript in `.cshtml` files. This automatically rules out any bundlers except perhaps Vite, but that doesn't work as well since some of the scripts are dynamically generated after the web app is launched. Other scripts simply don't work as modules (e.g. Moment.js) due to the very strange usage implementation in the web app.

Since there is a lot of legacy code that I have to support, rewriting or removing said problematic components is not an option. I have turned to the browser's native ESM support and I've worked on a separate branch that uses importmaps to point to specific JS files in the `node_modules` folder. However, during deployment I suspect that will be a problem since there are a lot of files (that bundlers omit when bundling) that we'd prefer do not remain in the published folder.

Is there any way, any NPM package, or any tool in general that extracts only the needed code from the `node_modules` folder and places them in a desired location **without** bundling them?